# Seeding data into MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, seed

I'm creating a MERN project and want a file to seed data into my database. Using sql I've done this by creating a seed file with a .db extension which I would then run as a script in my terminal. I am wondering how this is done for MongoDB and what file extension I should use, is this just a json file? I am also wondering what the proper way of doing this is. I was looking online but I see so many different ways that people do things so I'm just trying to figure out what the standard is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create each collection in a separate JSON or CSV file, and use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#mongoimport)